# Get all filled inputs with knockout bindings

Tags: javascript, typescript, knockout.js

I have viewModel with some observable properties. This viewModel is binded to searchForm. I need to create request only with filled inputs, in other words, I need to get all properties, where there are some value.

How can I get all fields where are some value?

```
class AdvancedSearchModel {
    clientKey: any = ko.observable('');
    uid: any = ko.observable('');
    name: any = ko.observable('');

    address1: any = ko.observable('');
    address2: any = ko.observable('');
    city: any = ko.observable('');
    province: any = ko.observable('');
    state: any = ko.observable('');
    country: any = ko.observable('');
    postalCode: any = ko.observable('');

    phone: any = ko.observable('');
    fax: any = ko.observable('');

    longitude: any = ko.observable('');
    latitude: any = ko.observable('');
}
```

---

Currently I see only one solution to check every field separatelly if it has value.

```
if(this.clientKey() != ''){ //...}
```

---

Another maybe shorter way (According to @user3297291 answer):

```
let whereObject: any = {};
Object.keys(locationModel).forEach(property => {
    if (!whereObject.hasOwnProperty(property) && locationModel[property]() != '') {
         whereObject[property] = { "eq": locationModel[property]() };
    }
});
```

But still I loop through every field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to somehow create a collection of the fields that are relevant. With that collection, you'll be able to create a computed object that filters out the fields without input.

Three ways to make such a collection:

- Use `Object.keys(viewModel)`: this will return each property of the viewmodel. You will have to limit the properties of the viewmodel to be only the ones you want in your data.
- Create a separate array of the form field names, e.g.: `[this.clientKey, this.uid, /* etc. */]`
- Create an object that holds the key names you want the fields to have in your final data along with the references to the viewmodel properties

### Example: explicitly defining which properties to include

Here's an example of how the last option could work:

- `formFields` holds the properties we want to include.
- `filledIn` subscribes to changes in all of those fields
- The `reduce` filters out properties without a value

```js
var ViewModel = function() {
  this.a = ko.observable("");
  this.b = ko.observable("");
  this.c = ko.observable("");

  var formFields = {
    "a": this.a,
    "b": this.b,
    "c": this.c
  };
  
  this.filledIn = ko.pureComputed(function() {
    var val;
    return JSON.stringify(Object.keys(formFields) // An array of all keys
      .reduce(function(result, key) {             // Create an object
        val = ko.unwrap(formFields[key]);         // See if there's a value
        if (val) result[key] = val;               // Add to new object if there is
        return result;
      }, {}), null, 2);                           // Stringify settings for UI
  }, this);
  
};

ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>

<input data-bind="textInput: a, attr: {placeholder: 'a'}">
<input data-bind="textInput: b, attr: {placeholder: 'b'}">
<input data-bind="textInput: c, attr: {placeholder: 'c'}">

<pre data-bind="text: filledIn"></pre>
```

### Example: including *all* properties of a viewmodel

If you don't like the "duplication" within `formFields`, you can refactor to something like this:

```js
var FormViewModel = function() {
  this.a = ko.observable("");
  this.b = ko.observable("");
  this.c = ko.observable("");
};

var ViewModel = function() {
  var self = this;
  
  this.form = new FormViewModel();
  
  this.filledIn = ko.pureComputed(function() {
    var val;
    return JSON.stringify(Object.keys(self.form)
      .reduce(function(result, key) {
        val = ko.unwrap(self.form[key]);
        if (val) result[key] = val;
        return result;
      }, {}), null, 2);
  });
  
};

ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>

<div data-bind="with: form">
  <input data-bind="textInput: a, attr: {placeholder: 'a'}">
  <input data-bind="textInput: b, attr: {placeholder: 'b'}">
  <input data-bind="textInput: c, attr: {placeholder: 'c'}">
</div>
<pre data-bind="text: filledIn"></pre>
```